# Using sed and/or awk, how can do a sed swap on all text in a file until I see a line matching a regex?

Tags: regex, sed, awk

How can I do a sed regex swap on all text that preceed a line matching a regex.

e.g. How can I do a swap like this

```
s/foo/bar/g
```

for all text that precedes the first point this regex matches:

```
m/baz/
```

I don't want to use [positive/negative look ahead/behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in my sed regex, because those are really expensive operations on big files.

Comment: I assume from your mention of lookahead/behind that you mean the first point in each line that matches, rather than the first point in the file? But the rest of the phrasing doesn't agree with that... was the lookaround referring to pattern matching on the entire file instead of line-by-line?

Comment: I was talking about the entire file.  I didn't know that sed worked line by line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that you want to do the substitution on every *line* preceding the given match, this is your answer:

The substitution takes an optional address range; you can use both numbers and patterns. In this case, start from line 1, go until your pattern:

```
sed '1,/baz/s/foo/bar/g'
```

In awk:

```
awk '
/baz/ { done = 1 }
{
    if (!done) {
        gsub(/foo/, "bar")
    }
    print
}'
```

(It's really short enough to leave out the line breaks, but they make it readable)

Comment: You might note that you cannot do '1,/baz/-1s/foo/bar/'.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's a very good point. If you want to avoid touching the line where /baz/ matched, this is suddenly very very difficult in sed - but awk would still be able to do it.

Comment: both your solution will change "foo" to "bar" if "baz" is not found

Comment: @ghostdog74: Is that not the desired behavior? My reading of "until first match" is that if there is no match, you go until the end.

Comment: @ghostdog74: I don't interpret that as a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

This variation on **Jefromi's** answer should do the trick of not touching the line that "baz" appears on as mentioned in **Jonathan's** comment.

```
sed '1,/baz/{/baz/!s/foo/bar/g}'
```

Comment: Wow, I should have thought of that. I was already thinking about all this nonsense reading next line in...  +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
123 abc 01
456 foo 02 bar
789 ghi
baz
blah1
blah2
foo bar

$ awk -vRS="baz" 'NR==1{gsub("foo","bar")}1' ORS="baz" file
123 abc 01
456 bar 02 bar
789 ghi
baz
blah1
blah2
foo bar
baz
```

use "baz" record separator , then the 1st record will be the record you want to change "foo" to "bar".

with sed, variation of Denni's solution to take care of "baz" at first line

```
sed '0,/baz/{/baz/!s/foo/bar/g}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
awk '/baz/{p=1};!p{gsub(/foo/,"bar")};1' file
```

or this:

```
sed '/baz/,$!s/foo/bar/g' file
```